# Stop pandas from drawing a line in area plot for missing values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When doing an area plot in pandas, it will always draw at least a thin line for every column. Even if that column is missing values in that range.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group a': [3, 2, 3, 2, 3],
    'group b': [np.nan, np.nan, 20, 42, 28],
    'day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
})
ax = df.plot.area(x='day')
```

[image: Example output]

I need it to only plot a line when there are actual values. So, in the example group b line should only start appearing on day 3, not day 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to set line-width to zero. Works for both zero and nan values

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sales': [3, 2, 3, 2, 3],
    'visits': [0, np.nan, 20, 42, 28],
    'day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
})
ax = df.plot.area(x='day', linewidth=0)
```

[image]